# Convert hexadecimal to binary on Linux CLI

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with lines (each of 631 characters) consisting of 16 hexadecimal numbers `0,1,2,...,9,A,B,...,F`. I would like to replace each number with the corresponding 4 bits of 0 and 1, i.e. 0 with 0000, 1 with 0001, ..., F with 1111 and then save the file as .bin. How can I do so in Linux terminal?

Some lines of my text file are:

```
85868D6B0FD5F3186DE92A7FC023CC848110FE61E3045B24BD905C8FDF34698794718CB2BAFF2AFC488C07B01510646141290A8FE55BF41F9D5033B13B31473FB4F7E199624370DC9C7587E5FB84B209B104B2BC194243EFC77C479BEA6778C73FB55939CB8654B1EB0B597CEA9507FE5A9636229BE0E7ECA27844D3A4AE16096D9DDC125728A1BF0C3623518311CF7CE629C15EA767E1F6C992106E86D962D47E307AE9F71FE5C6B664820E3D7521D0F783913E8A116BFD42C65FD2E28C9114CF4BFCB8A2AFD9979E7B5EBC7B59C7A31A7C12931D2C794EF5AED991B32560BBEFCC82D3A6AC6D371C7AC6C06DED6BCEFFC3D9E11A17B4738EA2ECF8CDD14805E57C50F973C6832DB94517A71C06E18329694B8CB7F7028730E54F74E27EF35B3D776A7E46A3F187691D460CBFBCD14BAC4AED32E5592AFDAEC5206
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
```

Comment: This question has an answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120324/hex-to-binary-conversion-in-bash)

Comment: `for n in $(cat myfile | tr 'a-f' 'A-F');do echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $n" | bc;done` then you may need to do some padding for binary numbers shorter than 4 digits

Comment: @MelBurslan +1 and you should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer to be marked as "solved"

`for n in $(cat myfile | tr 'a-f' 'A-F');do echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $n" | bc ;done`

Okay, in the light of what you have said and what I understood, I have a couple of suggestions to you. The first one, converts each hex line into a new binary line and puts a line break at the end of each line. here is that solution:

```
cat myfile | while read line
do
  len=${#line}
  binline=""
  index=1
  while [ ${index} -le ${len} ]
  do
    hex=$(echo ${line} | cut -c ${index} | tr 'a-f' 'A-F')
    bin=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; ${hex}"|bc)
    padbin=$(printf "%04d" ${bin})
    binline="${binline}${padbin}"
    (( index++ ))
  done
  echo ${binline} >> program.bin
done
```

And, if I am not mistaken, you are trying to use this binary file as a program to an embedded system or something similar. If that is the case the line breaks may present a problem. If this is the case, i.e., you want the whole file as one single humongous line, you can use the following snippet:

```
cat myfile | while read line
do
  len=${#line}
  index=1
  while [ ${index} -le ${len} ]
  do
     hex=$(echo ${line} | cut -c ${index} | tr 'a-f' 'A-F')
     bin=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; ${hex}"|bc)
     printf "%04d" ${bin} >> p2.bin
     (( index++ ))
  done
done
```

Having said all of this, if your hexadecimal values file is in  gigabytes size or even few hundred megabytes size, bash will complain and may throw a cryptic error. So, it is in your best interest to chop this input file to more manageable chunks and process them piece-by-piece.

Please note that, I wrote these scripts in the simplest for to understand. Hence it will have some performance penalties when you run them. 3 lines takes about 6 seconds of processing time. It is up to you to optimize it, if you find the wait intolerable.

Comment: Thank you ! And how can I save my file in .bin format?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `bin` format but you can output these numbers to a files named as `program.bin` for instance using redirection at the end of the command, i.e., `for n in $(cat myfile | tr 'a-f' 'A-F');do echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $n" | bc ;done >program.bin`, but since you mentioned the word program, I am assuming there has to be some other heading or trailing blocks for your machine to understand, this is a program, not a random string of `1`s and `0`s. At this point you are on your own.

Comment: OK, I got it ! Thanks ! But the terminal closes for my large file of 58 GB when I run the for loop. What can I do?

Comment: I tried for a small file, what I see in the output file is: 10000101100001101000110101101011000011111101010111110011000110000110\
11011110100100101010011111111100000000100011110011001000010010000001\
... After every 68 zeros and ones there is a backslash, how can I remove it and have all 0s and 1s one after the other?

Comment: could you please post a few lines from your original file, so that I can see and test my code snippet against it ? Please update your original post and put the lines there, not here as a comment.

Comment: That may be bc wrapping: "Since numbers are of arbitrary precision, some numbers may not be printable on a single output line.  These long numbers will be split across lines using the "\" as the last character on a line."

Comment: @user166316 Please see the newly added alternatives in my answer.

Comment: Thank you ! When I run the codes in Linux terminal, I receive the message "command not found", which command is unknown?

Comment: put whichever solution you want to use in a `file` using your favorite editor. `chmod 755 file` and `bash -x file` This should give you the status of the script as it runs. You can figure out where you are getting a `command not found` error. Although, other than `tr` and `bc` I don't see any other external commands. Hence can't figure out where you might be getting that error. There might be a typo on your side

Comment: I fixed the problem and managed to run the code, thanks! However, when I open the file p2.bin by matlab using fread('p2.bin','ubit1'), the numbers I see are 100011000000 ... at the beginning for 858... which have to be 100001011000 ... instead !

Answer (score 12):

**`xxd -r -p`**

Example:

```
sudo apt install xxd
printf 123456789ABCDEF0 | xxd -r -p | od -A n -t x1 -v
```

gives:

```
 12 34 56 78 9a bc de f0
```

`od` shows raw bytes as human readable bytes, which means that `xxd -r -p` did what we wanted and converted the human readable `123456789ABCDEF0` into corresponding raw bytes.

Tested on Ubuntu 19.04, xxd V1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want hex strings to be converted to binary strings (sequences of 8 `0` or `1` characters for each 2 hex digit character), as opposed to convert those to binary, I'd use `perl` for that:

```
$ echo 00ffaa | perl -lne 'print unpack "B*", pack"H*", $_'
000000001111111110101010
```

With `xxd`:

```
$ echo 00ffaa | xxd -p -r | xxd -b -g 0 -c 8 | cut -c11-74
000000001111111110101010
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use printf:

```sh
$ printf '%04d\n' 0
0000

$ printf '%04d\n' 1
0001
```

Or the POSIX Awk [stdlib library](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib):

```sh
$ awklib 'BEGIN {print base_conv("F", 16, 2)}'
1111
```